# Core Graphics or Stretchable Image?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiimage, core-graphics

If you have the option to use core graphics or stretchable UIImage (assuming either way will work) to render your graphics in your iOS app, which will you use? What's the pros and cons doing it one way over the other?

Comment: can you provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

`UIImage` is quite likley using CoreGraphics (or maybe CoreAnimation) under the covers. You can either do the same work yourself, and maybe make a mistake, or you can leverage `UIKit`'s well-tested implementation. The other potential advantage is that there may be non-obvious performance advantages gleaned by using `UIImage`. For instance, unlike on OS X, you can't manually create a `CGContext` backed by an `IOSurface` on iOS, but perhaps `UIImage` could do that by virtue of being able to use private API to do its job. (The truly curious can investigate what UIKit is doing using the debugger or `dtrace`.)

In short, use the highest level of abstraction that gets the job done (UIKit being a higher level API than CoreGraphics.) If `UIImage`'s stretched drawing routines get the job done for you, I can think of few reasons not to use them. One potential reason I can envision for not using `UIImage` routines might be if you were developing a cross-platform library intended to run on both OS X and iOS.

PS: "Being unacceptably slow in a way that doing it in a lower level API wouldn't be" would count in my mind as "*not* getting the job done," but you can't know that without trying both ways and measuring.

Comment: One thing I do like about CoreGraphics is it is resolution and device independent, whereas stretchable is not. Thoughts?

Comment: How do you figure? The source image "is what it is" -- which API you use to draw it can't change the resolution of the source material.

Comment: I am using CoreGraphics to render the entire thing - so it won't even use the source material that is used in stretched image at all.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't clear from your question's wording. The relative performance of those two options is hard to compare in general terms. For instance, drawing with CG primitives might be faster than decoding a compressed image, but you've got to cache the output, because redrawing every time the view displays won't be faster than using UIImage. It certainly seems that the most common choice is to use image resources. It's a trade off, and it's situation dependent. If your image has a lot of alpha blending, drawing will be slower, etc. At least loading an image from a file is predictable. :)